# Get a value per count of rows based on their value in PowerBI DAX for use in function

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's say I have the database of a hotel, it's structured somewhat like this:

| Guest Name | Revision Date | Check-In Date | Guest Room | Case Number | Checked-Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kurt Ambrose | 2022-01-18 | 2022-01-16 | 108 | 100000054 | null |
| John Forge | 2022-01-18 | 2022-01-16 | 222 | 100000050 | null |
| James Cutter | 2022-01-18 | 2022-01-12 | 106 | 100000042 | null |
| Kurt Ambrose | 2022-01-19 | 2022-01-16 | 108 | 100000054 | null |
| John Forge | 2022-01-19 | 2022-01-16 | 222 | 100000050 | Complete |
| James Cutter | 2022-01-19 | 2022-01-12 | 106 | 100000042 | null |
| Kurt Ambrose | 2022-01-20 | 2022-01-16 | 108 | 100000054 | null |
| James Cutter | 2022-01-20 | 2022-01-12 | 106 | 100000042 | null |
| Kurt Ambrose | 2022-01-21 | 2022-01-16 | 108 | 100000054 | null |
| James Cutter | 2022-01-21 | 2022-01-12 | 106 | 100000042 | null |
| Kurt Ambrose | 2022-01-22 | 2022-01-16 | 108 | 100000054 | null |
| James Cutter | 2022-01-22 | 2022-01-12 | 106 | 100000042 | null |
| John Forge | 2022-01-22 | 2022-01-22 | 111 | 100000055 | null |
| Serin Osman | 2022-01-22 | 2022-01-22 | 202 | 100000056 | null |
| Kurt Ambrose | 2022-01-23 | 2022-01-16 | 108 | 100000054 | null |
| James Cutter | 2022-01-23 | 2022-01-12 | 106 | 100000042 | null |
| John Forge | 2022-01-23 | 2022-01-22 | 111 | 100000055 | null |
| Serin Osman | 2022-01-23 | 2022-01-22 | 202 | 100000056 | Partial |

So in this case if I want to get an average time of stay in this database, what my mind tells me to do is to count case numbers per revision date, since I can't use names because John Forge checked out and then came back to the hotel and got a new Case Number, which counts as a new stay, which affects the average, so I'd need to count per Revision Date and Case Number and add that number to the calculation for the average, but exclude if there's text in the "Checked-Out" column. I'd like to use other kinds of metrics for my visualizations later as well.

The thing is, I don't know how to write this need in DAX for PowerBI or if it's even possible. May I have some help, please?

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected result for the dataset you posted is, and why?

Comment: What do you mean with expected result? I used the dataset as an example to explain the logic I'm trying to follow and why I need to use Revision Date and Case Number to begin to get statistics like average.

Comment: I mean what would the Average Time of Stay be for that example dataset, as manually calculated by you? Knowing what the result should be helps enormously when testing potential solutions.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. In this case, there are four people in total, but five different case numbers. So on this dataset, I'd like PowerBI to count how many instances of each 
different case number there are to make an average, so: 

100000042 -> 6 (days)
100000050 -> 1 (days)
100000054 -> 6 (days)
100000055 -> 2 (days)
100000056 -> 1 (days) 
 
So the sum of values is 14, divided by 5 cases equals an average value of 2.8 days.
Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **measure**:

```
Average Time of Stay :=
VAR MyTable =
    SUMMARIZE(
        Table1,
        Table1[Case Number],
        "Count", COUNTROWS( FILTER( Table1, Table1[Checked-Out] = "null" ) )
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX( MyTable, [Count] )
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. Although with the null part at "Checked-Out" I meant literal empty data, so I replaced line 6 with "Count", COUNTROWS( FILTER( Table1, ISBLANK(Table1[Checked-Out] ) ) )    But other than that, it worked, thank you.